# Change navigation bar positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm totally new to HTML and CSS. And I would like to get my navigation bar a little more to the left.

Now here is also a screenshot about what I mean https://prnt.sc/myh7gm
I would like to get it a couple px/cm to the left like you can see on here 
https://prnt.sc/myh75s

My code

```
<body>
<header>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
    /* navigation bar */

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    opacity: 0.;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Margin-right` is a fine way to do it. Check out the class I added to the `nav` element. Best practice to target a class with your CSS, that way your rules dont affect every `nav`, `ul`, `li` etc in your site.

```css
.main-navigation {
  margin-right: 50px; // whatever distance from the right you want
}

.main-navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.main-navigation li {
    float: right;
}

.main-navigation li a {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navigation li a:hover:not(.active) {
    opacity: 0.;
  }
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutme.html">About me</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding padding in the css

```
.navbar {
padding-left: 20px
/* any other rules you wnat to add*/
}
```

or left:20px

I can't see you links.

go to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_navbar_icon.asp for more ideas.